# How do i translate this to jQuery and make it work

Tags: jquery

the div is dynamic but it is allways 21 chars and in this format (7chars)-(13chars)

```
function Onload() {
    var n = 21;    
    var dh = getElementsByTagName('div');
    if (dh.length == n) {
        dh[0].style.right = 'auto !important';
        dh[0].style.left = '10px !important';
    };
}
```

what the best way to catch it and change the styling at the end of the load process with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming from the description that you only want to affect `div` elements that have a textual value which is 21 characters in length. If so, you can use `filter()` to select them, then `addClass()` to add the CSS rules.  Try this:

```js
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().length == 21;
  // return this.textContent.length == 21; // slightly faster alternative
}).addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo</div>
<div>1234567-1234567890123</div>
<div>foo</div>
```

Comment: Really, `getElementsByTagName('div').length` is different from `$(this).text().length`.

Comment: I'm aware. Hence why I'm going from the description of what the OP is trying to do, not the literal logic of the code in the question.

Comment: This function works but it won't target the div I need for some reason, maybe it is harder than I thought or maybe not possible

Comment: This are external assets that are loaded on the page, is that the reason? is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Link jQuery in your HTML page, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now to check if the length value of the div elements text is 21 then this should work:

```
// add a onload event to the window
$(window).on("load", function() {
  // loop through the divs
  $("div").each(function() {
    // check to see if the length of the div's text is 21
    if($(this).text().length == 21) {
      // change the div's css
      $(this).css({
        "right": "auto !important",
        "left": "10px !important"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @TânNguyễn Duplicate..? I don't see another answer like it. Rory's answer uses the filter method and adds a class, I'm looping though the elements and changing it's CSS. Can you clarify what makes my answer a duplicate?

Comment: Ya, duplicate in line `$(this).text().length == 21`. Checking for text length is 21 or not.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Just because both answers check the length of the text doesn't mean the answer is a duplicate. It's a vital part of the solution and can't be replaced and / or substituted.